# Can't save word as pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, ms-word, com-interop, word-automation

I have made a Word addin, which allows the user to click a button, chose a filename and save as a pdf file.

But very often, the user get this error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): (roughly translated from danish:) File is used by another program or user.

Eventhough the filename doesn't exists.

Here's my code:

```
If dlgSaveAsPDF.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        .ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName:= _
     dlgSaveAsPDF.FileName, ExportFormat:= _
     wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
     wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
     Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
     CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
     BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False)
    End With
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dlgSaveAsPDF.FileName)
End If
```

The file never gets saved.

Comment: Sure the file name has a pdf extension, and not retaining its doc(x) extension?

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be a Kaspersky problem...

http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280046

After following the faq, the error has not occured.

Can't understand why this is not fixed yet in Kaspersky ... hmmmm.